# Pandas.read_csv,is returning "NaN" value for 2 value that contain a string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am reading a file using `pd.read_csv()`. The file is correctly loaded into a data frame, but in my 90+ rows I have 2 rows where the value of col is set to "NaN", but there is a string value at these specific cells, nothing seems to show major differences with other row value so I don't know why it is happening.  Any idea?

for example one of the values I am supposed to get is "xcap.ims.mnc001.mcc208.pub.3gppnetwork" so nothing close to the basic na_filter set for `pd.read_csv()`

I tried to toggle off the `na_filter` option and the `keep_default_na` option but I just replaced "NaN" with an empty space.

Comment: You will need to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  It is probably a problem in your data or code, not in the pandas read_csv() function.

Comment: Please show a subset of the data file in a table including the "NaN" cells, and also the code you've used. It's easier to debug when we can see the table, the headers, the cell values, and the code also.